# Oracle APEX Popup LOV Performance Issue

Tags: oracle, popup, oracle-apex, lov

My company has an application built by Oracle APEX that contains popup LOV in some pages, recently users began complaining about those lists. Sometimes it takes much time to load, about 20 ~ 40 seconds.

I become responsible for following up with this issue, with no knowledge on that Oracle APEX. I suspected network first, so I pinged the server, and no issues.

If popup lists changed to drop down lists, latency issue will disappear.

What tests can I perform to identify this issue clearly?
How to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you run the query in the LOV directly in SQLPlus/Developer/Toad, does it still take a long time?

Comment: check exec plan for LOV query , see how much rows returns..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Tony no it doesn't.

Comment: @Анатолий I will do and feedback.

Comment: @АнатолийПредеин one of the popup lists returns 1200 records, another one returns 1600.

Comment: @Abbas 1600 records - it's not many data, important thing - it how those rows fetched... check execute plan of query's, it show you why processing is to slow..

Answer (score 0):

We have got a few separate issue here:

- By changing to dropdown lists (I assume you are talking about select lists) the latency will reduce mainly because pop lov load by demand and select lists load beforehand. Which should make page load time increase.
- Run the query in you PL/SQL tool too check it's speed, it should be a bit faster than in the app, but still slow... Or do something like "check exec plan" the way it was mentioned in the comments.
- Finally, I had some similar issues and although we try our best to optimize the query, it was still a bit to slow. So What we did was to provide parent filter for the pop lov. The change was HUGE and the data loaded much faster.